# In Freebase MQL, how can I write a query to get the name a organization's parent?

Tags: freebase, mql

For a list of organizations I need to get their parents. In freebase.com's query editor, I am using the following query:

{
  "id":            "/en/daihatsu_motor_company",
  "/organization/organization/parent":{id:null}
}​

And I am getting the following result:

{
  "code":          "/api/status/ok",
  "result": {
    "/organization/organization/parent": {
      "id": "/m/04kjl82"
    },
    "id": "/en/daihatsu_motor_company"
  },
  "status":        "200 OK",
  "transaction_id": "cache;cache03.p01.sjc1:8101;2012-07-10T22:54:06Z;0030"
}

However, I am expecting the id: toyota_motor_corporation.

From freebase.com's query editor, I can click on the id ("id": "/m/04kjl82") which is a link to view with the info I need:

http://www.freebase.com/view/m/04kjl82

How can I get directly the name of the parent company or its id (in the example toyota_motor_corporation)?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Claudio's answer is close, but if you actually want the ID, you need to tweak the query slightly since the default property returned is the name, not ID.  This will get you the ID:

```
{
  "id": "/en/daihatsu_motor_company",
  "/organization/organization/parent": {
    "parent": {"id":null}
  }
}​
```

which will return

```
  "result": {
    "/organization/organization/parent": {
      "parent": {
        "id": "/en/toyota_motor_corporation"
      }
    },
    "id": "/en/daihatsu_motor_company"
  }
```

Having said that, you should consider [using the MID](http://www.freebase.com/queryeditor?q=%7B%22id%22%3a%22/en/daihatsu_motor_company%22,%22/organization/organization/parent%22%3a%7B%22parent%22%3a%7B%22mid%22%3anull%7D%7D%7D) instead of the ID since that's the recommended identifier these days.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is returning the id of the organization relationship between a Parent and a Child. What you want is the parent and you can get it with the following query:

```
{
  "id": "/en/daihatsu_motor_company",
  "/organization/organization/parent": {
    "parent": null
  }
}​
```

which returns

```
{
  "code":          "/api/status/ok",
  "result": {
    "/organization/organization/parent": {
      "parent": "Toyota Motor Corporation"
    },
    "id": "/en/daihatsu_motor_company"
  },
  "status":        "200 OK",
  "transaction_id": "cache;cache03.p01.sjc1:8101;2012-07-11T21:50:01Z;0045"
}
```